# Eclipse variable ${project.classpath} not available during ant build

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I checked out an foreign project from a vcs, that uses java, groovy and was built using eclipse ide. There is also an ant build.xml. When I try to build the whole project within eclipse, it works. But when I start the ant task, the build fails with not finding ${project.classpath}. The ant build is needed in order to build this project with teamcity automatically.

I tried relative and also fixed paths, but the problem is the usage of groovy and other related projects. Eclipse can resolute the "magic classpath", but ant doesn't know what to do. Me neither ;) (I also tried to convert the project to maven etc. pp.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="build" name="Create jar">
    <target name="build">
    <path id="classpath" path="${project.classpath}" />
        ........
```

The error message is the following:

```
Warning: Could not find resource file "C:\Users\username\git\projectname\project\${project.classpath}" to copy.
```

I hope, somebody can help me. Again: The goal is to build this eclipse project with the teamcity build server automatically. It doesn't matter what technology is used (ant, maven etc...).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"But when I start the ant task"* How are you starting the Ant task?

Comment: Using eclipse: double click the build-jar.xml, selecting the target "build", right click -> run as -> Ant Build Task
Teamcity: Build Step "Ant", config file: "build-jar.xml". The rest is done by teamcity.

Comment: In `build.xml` where does `${project.classpath}` location referring to ?

Comment: Now i know: Nothing to. The author might have thought, eclipse would resolve this variable itself. The question is, is there a way to accessand parse the .classpath-file (eclipse) from ant? The problem is, that groovy support is being needed. I know maven a bit, but don't get correct classpaths wirh maven or ant to compile. Just some libs and gropvy is needed. Maybe someone has experiences with this constellation and can give me some advice. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I somehow got it. I re-started with maven, added the maven groovy compiler etc. and tried to compile. Didn't really work, until I added the Bintray repo to get newer maven-groovy-plugins. That worked better. Then played around with the versions, and finally used non-recent versions and it works fine. It's a jungle of bugs out there with java, eclipse, groovy, maven.... Thanks.